# thread::detach during concurrent thread::join in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, language-lawyer

In the following program, during one thread (main) is performing `thread::join`, another thread (x) calls `thread::detach`:

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    auto t = std::thread([] {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds(1000) );
    } );
    auto x = std::thread([&t] {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds(500) );
        if ( t.joinable() )
        {
            std::cout << "detaching t..." << std::endl;
            t.detach();
        }
    } );
    std::cout << "joining t..." << std::endl;
    t.join();
    x.join();
    std::cout << "Ok" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It work fine in GCC's `libstdc++` and Clang's `libc++` printing

```
joining t...
detaching t...
Ok
```

but in Visual Studio the program terminates with not-zero exit code before printing `Ok`. Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/v1nEfaP7a

Is it a bug in Visual Studio or the program contains some undefined behavior?

Comment: `std::thread` object itself is not thread-safe. Calling `join` and `joinable` on it from two threads concurrently exhibits undefined behavior by way of a data race.

Comment: How is this different from e.g. one thread pushing to a vector and another popping?

Comment: What you have is one thread patiently waiting for a `thread` to advertise that the thread it represents has finished when another thread calls the `detach`, function so that the `thread` no longer represents a thread. You could just as easily get the other obvious result, the thread is detached before it can be joined. Or you could get the thread being detached *while* it is being joined. All three cases are unpleasant. Don't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `join` nor `detach` are `const`-qualified and therefore the implementation is allowed to modify internal memory of the `thread` object without having to provide any guarantees of write/write or write/read data race avoidance on unsynchronized calls to these member functions per the default data race avoidance requirements of [res.on.data.races].

There is also no exception to this rule mentioned in [thread.threads] or anywhere else for these functions.

Therefore calling `join` and `detach` without establishing a happens-before relation between the two calls is a data race and causes undefined behavior.

Even without the `detach` call, there is still a write/read data race on the `join`/`joinable` pair of calls.